# FormGroup: Dynamic input type breaks value attribute binding

Tags: angular, formgroups

It took me a couple days, but I narrowed it down to the type attribute.
In my StackBlitz, the first radio set is just putting an empty string in the FormGroup object. To fix it, just change line 9 from `[type]="question.type"` to `type="radio"`.

Is there another attribute I should be using to do dynamic input types? (I wanted to try to do checkboxes and radio buttons in the same pass of a larger ngSwitch.)

[Here is my StackBlitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-aysffh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**Update:** Looks like [it's a bug](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7329) that isn't getting fixed and we should use ngSwitch / ngIfs instead.